# AMPscript - data extension data manipulation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am currently having a problem with salesforce email personalisation using journey builder field personalisation.

We are based in AUS and use `dd/mm/yyyy` format but the data pulling through from Salesforce CRM to Marketing cloud automatically updates the CRM field value to CTU so when we have a date set as `10/04/2023` for the field 'latest delivery date' and we pull this through as a journey token using AMP `%%opurtunity:syncedquote:latestdeliverydate__c%%` the customer receives the email stating the date as 4/10/2023 12:00:00 AM. Is there a solution to this?

I tested out using inline AMP but no success with that.

`%%[Output(format([%%opurtunity:syncedquote:latestdeliverydate__c],"dd/MM/yyyy"))]%%`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use inline ampscript like this. The correct format would be:

```
%%[Output(Format(AttributeValue("opurtunity:syncedquote:latestdeliverydate__c"),"dd/MM/yyyy"))]%%
```

Also, are you sure about the spelling (opurtunity vs opportunity)?